# What's the most optimal way of implementing outlier detection on GPU?

Tags: computer-vision, gpu

I have a set of keypoint correspondences between two images and now I'd like to perform outlier detection on GPU (CUDA/OpenCL) in order to select inliers.

I was thinking about using RANSAC with the 8-point algorithm but then I noticed the algorithm requires to perform SVD of an 8x9 matrix.

The problem is that every routine performing SVD I found contains severe branching (loops, conditions) which would result in divergence between threads.

Therefore I'd like to ask what's an optimal way to detect outliers/inliers on GPU? Does there exist an effective implementation of 8-point algorithm without SVD?